# What is the easiest way to install a R web application through RApache?

Tags: apache, web-applications, r, hosting, web-hosting

I use windows XP and R for my desktop use. And a shared hosting account (at some company) for my web hosting needs.

I wish to create an R web application and I understand that one such way is by using R with Apache through [RApache](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/) , but since my current shared hosting plan doesn't allow me to install RApache I am a bit stuck.

So... (and here's my question) what would be the easiest/fastest/cost-effective way to get started?

- Buying a more expensive hosting package ?
- Hosting the thing myself? (on windows ?!)
- switch to some other hosting company that permits the use of RApache?

Any suggestion will be most helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Self-hosting is an option if you insist on using RApache. This might be easier than you think. Here's a link to a [blog post](http://blog.leahculver.com/2009/07/my-own-server.html) i read a month ago before i decided to buy the hardware and server my own files. i just watched this seven minute YouTube video tutorial entitled "[R Web Application–'Hello World' using RApache](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/r-web-application-hello-world-using-rapache-7min-video-tutorial/)"  I believe this was just posted today.

In seven minutes, the author walks through building a "hello world" Site using RApache then walks through a more ambitious example, building a user-input form to collect inputs then deliver them to a particular R function--pretty much a exemplary slice of what i suspect most people would want to use RApache for.

A second option is using a web framework. My recommendation here is [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). Why? It's written in Python so you can access R functionality via the python bindings (RPy2). Second, if you are not an experienced web developer, Django is in many ways, a great framework to begin with because it's truly a "full-stack" solution--it works more or less out of the box. In addition, there is a substantial and growing body of quality step-by-setp tutorials, code snippets, and even packaged django Sites, to learn from.

Comment: Hi Doug,

Many thanks for replying and the link.

This video was also what I watched toady, and what excited me to try and do it myself (only to find out my hosting provider wouldn't support it).

Which leaves me with the question - what would be the easiest/fastest/cheapest way for doing that.

Thanks again :)

Tal

Comment: no problem. i just noticed that i originally left out a link on self-hosting (as well as my recommendation for it). It's in there now.

Comment: Not sure how rpy2 would go with your hosting company, either.  It requires R >= 2.8 compiled as shared library.

Answer (score 3):

it seems they provide a VMWare image to get up and running quickly.

I suggest you download VMWare player and try the image. Since RApache isn't available for Windows, this is the most simple way, I guess. I wouldn't use that for hosting, but I would first try whether this stack is actually the right thing for your app. Also, this allows you testing things locally.

Comment: Running the VM is certainly the fastest way to get up and running with RApache: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/vm.html

Answer (score 1):

Doug,
Should I read your suggestion as saying that a Django app can call the RPy2 functionality without RApache? If so, that sounds like a solution for folks on shared hosting who can't install the RAPache module.

Comment: This is true, but requires a Django host that also has RPy2 or lets you install your own Python modules as well as having R installed (or lets you install your own software).
Not terribly complicated stuff, but unless your host is small or cares a lot about it's customers - you will probably not find this everywhere.